# Implementing an association between 2 classes

Tags: uml

Consider the following association between the 2 classes

.[image]

Here the association means, In the class `Log` I have an array of `Traces`. and in class `Trace` there is an object of `Log`.

Here I have a problem in implementation these 2 classes now.
If I want to make `Log` instance, I need an array of `Trace` and when I go to make an instance of `Trace`, again I need an `Log` object. And this loop is continuing.

So am i in wrong way?

Comment: A `Log` contains several `Trace` instances, but do the `Trace` instances need to know (or access) the `Log` instance they are part of?

Comment: yes, they need.

Comment: You need to distinguish between "Owns" association and "Uses" association. Once you determine this, you can use the correct UML representation as in: http://usna86-techbits.blogspot.de/2012/11/uml-class-diagram-relationships.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `Trace` instance to create an **array** of `Trace` objects. You just need a typed array.

Therefore it's obvious how to implement this: create an empty array in the `Log` constructor, and when something noteworthy happens, create a `Trace` that knows its `Log`, and add it to the array.

There are other, more complicated situations, but so far you haven't shown anything that requires breaking any kind of cycle to work.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how is going to be created first.

You can create the traces and when you plug the traces into the log you just add a function in Trace to specify the father log

I didn't test this idea yet but I believe it will work.